# Ipython raw_input work around?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a Python program that wants to accept raw_input which Ipython notebook does not do. (a known limitation)

What is a recommended way to achieve the functionality? (work around?) What I'd like to do is to be able to run the program, accept input and respond..(will be choices determined based on information retrieved), and also prompting for user id and password info..

Of course I'd like to do as little violence to the existing code as possible.

I found IPython.utils.io.raw_input_ext(prompt='', ps2='... ') in the Ipython docs but it calls raw_input and gets the same not implemented error

Comment: For the notebooks that I made for others, I put the "configurable" variables in a separate cell at the top of the notebook, with a nice heading in a markdown cell above it.

Comment: I really want to do it interactively it will make an interactive idea I have really nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Last developement version of IPython now support raw_input in notebook. (since beginning of may 2013 for future reader)

Comment: Could you give us a pointer about it? Does it support password hidding (with '*' character as mask)?